# Get wordpress taxonomy slug name(s) to use as div class

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, slug

I'm trying to mark up my posts using their custom taxonomy slug as the div class so that they can be filtered...

So far what I have displays the taxonomy name but what I need is the slug so I have a nice-space-free-name, I have the below so far outputting the name:

```
 <div class="box-item cocktails-box 
 <?php $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'cocktail_type', '', ' ', '' ) );
 echo $terms_as_text; ?>">
```

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm getting a bald patch from scratching my head on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ambitious Amoeba's answer works. But have you looked into the `post_class` function? It'd do what you want, and save you a lot of trouble. Just use this as your div opener:

```
<div <?php post_class('box-item cocktails-box'); ?>>
```

where you pass the classes you want applied to all posts as a list or array, and let WordPress handle the rest (it'll add classes for all taxonomies that the post is in, and you can [filter it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) to add additional class depending on the view, if you want).

Comment: but then he gets a lot of unrelated classes too, and most likely he'll need to add more specific CSS rules to avoid conflicts (this increases CSS size)

Comment: Thanks for your help I managed to add the taxonomy term_id to the post_class function

Answer (score 1):

taxonomy slug, or the taxonomy terms slug?
I assume you mean the last:

```
<div class="box-item cocktails-box 
<?php foreach(get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'cocktail_type') as $term)
         echo $term->slug; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks this was close but pulled in the slugs with no spaces so they wouldn't work as classes, I actually ended up getting the term_id by adding some functions to the post_class

Comment: yes, you would need to change `echo $term->slug;` with `echo $term->slug." ";`. I forgot to do that...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really answer, but I adapted One Trick Pony's solution into a list for my own purposes. I thought I'd repost in case it might be of use to anyone.

```
<ul><?php foreach(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tool' , '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' ) as $term)
     echo '<li>'.$term->slug.'</li>' ?></ul>
```